# How to pass model from razor view to controller using ajax call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am building a .NET 5.0 application. I want to send a Model from Razor Page to the Controller named `AJAX` through an AJAX call.

My model is bound to the page form. I have tried passing a single string but am unable to find value at the other end. I have the same name in the JSON string and the parameter name in the controller method.

I have tried the `[FromBody]` tag and several other ways. My Network shows data is passed by I received `null` in parameter.

[Page Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYEFQ.png)

```
<div class="form-group row mb-3">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></span>
         <input asp-for="IndexEmail.Name" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col">
      <input value="Send" onclick="SendEmail()" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
   </div>
</div>
```

[AJAX Call to Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAPIg.png): 1

```
function SendEmail() {
    debugger;
    if ($("form").valid()) {

        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({Name: $("#displayname").val(),Subject: $("#subject").val(),EmailAddress: $("#emailaddress").val(),MessageBody: $("#messagebody").val()});
        $("body").addClass("loading");
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Ajax/SendGrid_SendEmail",
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            }
        }).done(function (data) {

            $("body").removeClass("loading");

        });
    }
}
```

AJAX Call to the controller: 2

```
 function SendEmail() {
        debugger;
        if ($("form").valid()) {
            //var email = {};
            //email.Name = $("#displayname").val();
            var jsonData = { EmailAddress: $("#emailaddress").val(), MessageBody: $("#messagebody").val(), Name: $("#displayname").val(), Subject: $("#subject").val()};
            $("body").addClass("loading");
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("SendGrid_SendEmail", "Ajax")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                    data: $("#subject").val() 
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {

                $("body").removeClass("loading");

                });
        }
    }
```

Model To Pass-through ajax call. it is bound to my razor page

```
 public class IndexEmail
    {

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MessageBody { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> SendGrid_SendEmail(string data)
{
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `$("#displayname").val()` to get the value, but you forget to add `id='displayname'`, and you also need to add `[FromBody]IndexEmail data` in controller function.

#### My test result.

[image]

#### My test code.

```
@model dotnet5MVC.Models.IndexEmail
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256- iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group row mb-3">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></span>
            <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" id="displayname" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col">
        <input value="Send" onclick="SendEmail()" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
    </div>
</div>


<script>
 function SendEmail() {
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ Name: $("#displayname").val(), Subject: $("#subject").val(), EmailAddress: $("#emailaddress").val(), MessageBody: $("#messagebody").val() });
        $("body").addClass("loading");
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("SendGrid_SendEmail", "Ajax")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            data: jsonData ,
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                }
            }).done(function (data) {

            $("body").removeClass("loading");

            });
}
</script>
```

#### My test code in Controller.

```
public class AjaxController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> SendGrid_SendEmail([FromBody]IndexEmail data)
    {
        var aa = data;
        return Json("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I saw your answer late because I had already fixed my code. Your answer is also correct. My problem was not using FormBody in Controller and Json.Stringify in AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. See below-updated code.

1. Form HTML, Only for Name field. All other fields have similar HTML. The only difference is Id

   ```
             <div class="form-group row mb-3">
             <div class="col">
             <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></span>
              <input id="displayname" asp-for="IndexEmail.Name" class="form- 
              control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
              </div>
             </div>
             </div>
   ```
2. AJAX Call on Send Button

   ```
   function SendEmail() {
        if ($("form").valid()) {
            var jsonData = { EmailAddress: $("#emailaddress").val(), MessageBody: $("#messagebody").val(), Name: $("#displayname").val(), Subject: $("#subject").val() };

            $("body").addClass("loading");
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "Ajax/SendGrid_SendEmail",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                }
            }).done(function (data) {
                debugger;
                $("body").removeClass("loading");

            });
        }
    }
   ```
3. Controller

   ```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool> SendGrid_SendEmail([FromBody] IndexEmail jsonData)
    {
        try
        {}
     }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
   ```
4. Json Data Received in Controller Action Parameter
   [image: Json Received]